# Tmux giving me 'Conneciton refused' after upgrade to Mavericks

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I finally upgraded to Mavericks and now when I try to start tmux via tmuxinator I get the folowing:

`unknown option: default-path
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
no sessions`

I uninstalled/re-installed tmux via brew but still same thing.  I've read some various write ups on the net about fixing the default-path issue in 1.9 but nothing has worked so far.

Any help appreciated - I'd like to get back to coding ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The default-path *might* be a red herring.

One thing that caught me out on a recent migration to a new machine was that I didn't install the 'reattach-to-user-namespace' command that I had on the old machine.

If you have a line like :

```
set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"
```

in your ~/.tmux.conf ((or anything else that calls an external command) try commenting it out, i.e.

```
#set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"
```

and launching tmuxinator again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  The problem was a conflict in my config.  I started from scratch and added item by item and found my culprit, a couple experimental lines I added a long while ago and since forgot what they actually did.

The thing that's weird is it wasn't a problem before the upgrade to Mavericks.